# gnuplot, two y-ranges far apart

Tags: range, gnuplot

Is it possible to plot two ranges which are far apart each other?

I mean, if I have a dataset like [ 1, 2, 3, 1001, 1001, 1003 ],
can I draw a plot like this?

```
     |
1003 |     x
1002 |     x
1001 |     x
1000 |    
     |
=====================  omission
     |
   4 |
   3 |     x
   2 |     x
   1 |     x
     -------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out this link: 
[Gnuplot surprising - Broken axes graph in gnuplot](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/10/broken-axes-graph-in-gnuplot.html). The author presents three examples of plotting a grqph with a broken x axis.

Answer (score 1):

Three helpful examples:

http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/10/broken-axes-graph-in-gnuplot-3.html

http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/broken.html

http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/

It is not straightforward.