# How can I divide the axis range?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make a 2D plot with **gnuplot** with some data of 2 columns with different Y-ranges but same X-range.

The Y-range for the first column are [1.112:1.118] while Y-range for second column are [4.445:4.451] so I need a way to fix both different ranges in the same axis finding a way to divide it (or to delete values between 1.118 and 4.445).

If the range was [1.112:4.451] the graph would just show two horizontal lines because the variation in each column is really small.

This image describes my question better than text I guess. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cgr4.png

Comment: It is quite tedious, See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7983895/2604213

Comment: Or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17683126/2043505) for a histogram.